# android manifest merger failed after adding Firebase UI to my dependency

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

I have upgraded to android studio canary and trying to add firebase UI to my app but am getting the following error:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.1) from [com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35
    is also present at [com.android.support:design:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:23:9-25:38 to override.
```

It seems to be some dependency problem but cant figure it out yet. My gradle file is as follow

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rainbow.dili"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:12.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.tbuonomo.andrui:viewpagerdotsindicator:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta6'
    compile 'com.droidninja:filepicker:2.0.7'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have been advised to get the same version for

```
compileSdkVersion 26
```

and

```
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
```

but still get the same error. What might be causing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an old version of `firebaseui` that is not compatible with version `12.0.1` of firebase, to solve this:

Change the following:

```
 compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.3.0'
```

to this:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:3.3.0'
```

more info here:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries